# Selective Typedefs Inheritance at Compile Time

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, multiple-inheritance

Imagine I have a big list of `typedef`s that I don't want to repeat for all classes, and I create a base class:

```cpp
template<class Derived>
class TypesDefs
{
    using ptr = std::shared_ptr<Derived>;
    //... many of them
};
```

Then I implement some concrete classes:

```cpp
class A : public TypesDefs<A>
{
};
```

My problem, as expected, is when I do:

```cpp
class C: public TypesDefs<C>, public A
{
};
```

The `C::ptr` becomes ambiguous as it could be `TypesDefs<A>::ptr` or `TypesDefs<C>::ptr`.

Any idea how I can define the types following the same/working above logic, please?

I tried some tricks with `std::enable_if` to always inherit the first time if the class is not derived already from `TypeDefs`, but got some compiling issues. I also tried virtual inheritance, but no luck.

Comment: If you have an explicit public inherit from TypesDefs<C> for class C, then it make sense to privately inherit A doesn't it? And anything you wish to access within A you can explicit say 'using A::ptr123;'

Comment: You can continue the CRTP approach to the most-derived class as you would in usual inheritance.

Comment: @Meng-ZeChen I still need to access some functionalities from the A class, my example is simplified, but I need public inheritance from A.

Comment: @user17732522 then I have to pollute all my code with the template arg, especially impossible if I am storing the C in a container

Comment: @SpeakX I messed up my previous comment and the correct solution didn't fit into the character limit, but maybe you got the idea.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks so much, yet got it! It still looks hacky but I might go with that if no answers. The only problem with above is I need to do this for all sequence of classes, like if D inherits from A and then E inherits from D, I have to do the above for D as well, which becomes dirty. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Do you really need inheritance? Can't you use `TypesDefs<A>::ptr` instead of `A::ptr`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think that solves the goal, thanks so much. Not what I optimally want, but makes sense. I could use macros as well and declare the types inside the class. Thank you

Comment: If you wish to inherit all of them as public, I'd go for slightly indirect way. Instead of directly defining lots of typedef in TypesDefs template, you can have a nested untemplated class call 'types' (yes, within your TypesDefs template), and then defining all alias within that 'types' nested class. Then, for all derived class like A or C, they can just say 'using types = typename TypesDefs<X>::types'. IMO this is much explicit in user's POV as well. But it's a indirect solution anyway.

Comment: @Meng-Ze Chen Amazing, thanks so much, will go with this. I don't need types i guess, i could just do: using types = TypesDefs<A>; inside A.